# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

Tags: javascript

La cuestión es la siguiente, este erro me salta A VECES. No siempre, asumo que debe ser un problema de que los elementos del DOM se crean dinámicamente tras leer un json y crear así la página.

El código es este:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    const DOTS      = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
    const SECTIONS  = document.getElementsByTagName('section');

    window.addEventListener("scroll", () => detectSection());
    detectSection();

    function detectSection(){
        for(let i = 0; i < SECTIONS.length; i++){
            let top = SECTIONS[i].offsetTop;
    
            if(this.window.scrollY >= top){
                setActive(i);
            }
        }
    }

    function setActive(i){    
        for(dot of DOTS)
        dot.classList.remove('active');
        DOTS[i].classList.add('active');
    }
});
```

Lo metí en un evento load porque sino obtenía las constantes con valor vacío. Ahora el problema es el que viene en el título, a veces no se carga lo suficientemente rápido. ¿Cómo podía hacerlo para que nunca ocurra esto?

Gracias de antebrazo.

Comment: ¿Los elementos se crean al momento de cargar la pagina (load) o se pueden ir agregando/quitando posteriormente al evento?

Comment: Creo que lo más lógico es hacer las queries dentro de la función detectSection y asegurarte de que el número de secciones no es mayor que el número de puntos (dots)

Comment: Podrías llamar a la funcion (_que le estas pasando al onload_) despues de que todos los elementos se agregaron a la página.

Comment: Cristian, los elementos se crean al cargar la página, por eso creo que tiene el conflicto, no se crean siempre a la misma velocidad.
Pablo, pero entonces haría las queries cada vez que hiciera scroll, ¿no sería más lógico que estuvieran al cargar la página y luego que trabaje con ello?
Marcos, los elementos los hago desde otro .js, pero no lo hago desde un evento onload. No se cómo implementarlo correctamente pues.